# My LCD connected to ATmega16 is not displaying anything

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, lcd, atmel

My 16 x 2 LCD is connected in 4 bit mode on the lower nibble to an ATMEGA16. Here are the connections:

VSS - GND
VDD - VCC
V0 - POTENTIOMETER
RS - PC6
RW - PC5
E - PC4
D4 - PC0
D5 - PC1
D6 - PC2
D7 - PC3
A - VCC (through 330 ohm resistor)
K - GND

This is the lcd.h file:

```c
#include "lcd.c"

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
void lcdCommand(unsigned char cmnd)
{
    _delay_us(100);
    
    LCD_PRT = (LCD_PRT & 0xF0) | (cmnd >> 4);       //Send high nibble d4-d7 to data port (Data pins on LOW Nibble of port)
    //LCD_PRT = (LCD_PRT & 0x0F) | (cmnd & 0xF0);       //Send high nibble d4-d7 to data port (Data pins on HIGH Nibble of port)
    LCD_PRT &= ~(1<<LCD_RS);        //RS=0 for command
    LCD_PRT &= ~(1<<LCD_RW);        //RW=0 for write
    LCD_PRT |= (1<<LCD_EN);         //EN=1 for H=to-L pulse
    _delay_us(1);                   //Wait to make enable wide
    LCD_PRT &= ~(1<<LCD_EN);        //EN = 0 for H-to-L pulse
    
    _delay_us(20);                  //Wait to make enale wide

    LCD_PRT = (LCD_PRT & 0xF0) | (cmnd & 0x0F);;        //Send low nibble d0-d3 to data port
    LCD_PRT |= (1<<LCD_EN);         //EN=1 for H=to-L pulse
    _delay_us(1);                   //Wait to make enable wide
    LCD_PRT &= ~(1<<LCD_EN);        //EN = 0 for H-to-L pulse
}
//*************************************************************************************
void lcdData(unsigned char data)
{
    _delay_us(100);  //*****NEW****
    
    LCD_PRT = (LCD_PRT & 0xF0) | (data >> 4);       //Send high nibble d4-d7 to data port
    LCD_PRT |= (1<<LCD_RS);         //RS=1 for data
    LCD_PRT &= ~(1<<LCD_RW);        //RW=0 for write
    LCD_PRT |= (1<<LCD_EN);         //EN=1 for H=to-L pulse
    _delay_us(1);                   //Wait to make enable wide
    LCD_PRT &= ~(1<<LCD_EN);        //EN = 0 for H-to-L pulse
    
    _delay_us(20);                  //Wait to make enale wide

    LCD_PRT = (LCD_PRT & 0xF0) | (data & 0x0F);;        //Send low nibble d0-d3 to data port
    LCD_PRT |= (1<<LCD_EN);         //EN=1 for H=to-L pulse
    _delay_us(1);                   //Wait to make enable wide
    LCD_PRT &= ~(1<<LCD_EN);        //EN = 0 for H-to-L pulse

}
//*************************************************************************************
void lcd_init()
{
    LCD_DDR = 0xFF;                 //LCD Port is output

    LCD_PRT &= ~(1<<LCD_EN);        //LCD_EN = 0
    _delay_us(2000);                    //Wait for stable power.
    lcdCommand(0x33);               //$33 for 4-bit mode
    _delay_us(100);
    lcdCommand(0x32);               //$32 for 4-bit mode
    _delay_us(100);
    lcdCommand(0x28);               //$28 for 4-bit mode
    _delay_us(100);                 //wait
    lcdCommand(0x0e);               //Display on, cursor on
    _delay_us(100);
    lcdCommand(0x01);               //Clear LCD
    _delay_us(2000);
    lcdCommand(0x06);               //Shift cursor right
    _delay_us(100);                 //wait
}
//*************************************************************************************
void lcd_gotoxy(unsigned char x, unsigned char y)
{
    unsigned char firstCharAdr[] = {0x80, 0xC0, 0x94, 0xD4};    //Table 12-5

    lcdCommand(firstCharAdr[y-1] + x-1);
    _delay_us(100);
}
//*************************************************************************************
void lcd_print(char *str)
{
    unsigned char i=0;

    while(str[i]!=0)
    {
        lcdData(str[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
//*************************************************************************************
void clear_lcd()
{
    lcdCommand(0x01);               //Clear LCD
    _delay_us(2000);                    //wait
}
//*************************************************************************************
//Copies string from flash memory to LCD at x y position
//const uint8_t welcomeln1[] PROGMEM="AVR LCD DEMO\0";
//CopyStringtoLCD(welcomeln1, 3, 1);    
void CopyStringtoLCD(const char* FlashLoc)
{
    uint8_t i;
    
    for(i=0;(uint8_t)pgm_read_byte(&FlashLoc[i]);i++)
    {
        lcdData((uint8_t)pgm_read_byte(&FlashLoc[i]));
    }
}
```

this is the lcd.h File:

```c
#ifndef LCD_H_
#define LCD_H_
#define F_CPU 4000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

#define LCD_PRT PORTC               //LCD DATA PORT
#define LCD_DDR DDRC                //LCD DATA DDR
#define LCD_PIN PINC                //LCD DATA PIN
#define LCD_RS  PC6                 //LCD RS
#define LCD_RW  PC5                 //LCD RW
#define LCD_EN  PC4                 //LCD EN

void lcdCommand(unsigned char);
void lcdData(unsigned char);
void lcd_init();
void lcd_gotoxy(unsigned char, unsigned char );
void lcd_print(char *);
void clear_lcd();
unsigned char GetKey(void);
void CopyStringtoLCD(const char*);

#endif /* LCD_H_ */
```

Comment: @RussellH - Hi, Re: "*THis looks more like a programming question than an electronics design question*" Yes, true, but firmware questions (especially when interfacing with hardware) are [on-topic](/help/on-topic) here, as well as on SO.

Comment: Saeed Bowman - Hi, As you are new here, please see the site [tour] & [help] for the main site rules and to see how Stack Exchange differs from typical forums. I'm sorry to say that there's a lack of detail & clarity to the question. (Can you add the schematic?) I've fixed the formatting so the code now displays properly. However you state that two pieces of code are both lcd.h. I think only the 2nd one is. The 1st one doesn't make much sense to me - it's #include-ing lcd.c (which you haven't shown here) & there's no main{} so we don't know which of the functions you're actually calling etc.

Comment: (cont'd) We need to know what troubleshooting you have done so far & also the actual test case you have i.e. what Stack Overflow call a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Have you got any evidence that it's a firmware problem, not a hardware problem? Have you used an oscilloscope to view the LCD interface signals to see what is happening, or is that not allowed in this project/test? The more details you can give site members, the more help you're likely to get. Please [edit] the question to answer those points & add detail. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried turning the contrast pot? What's the voltage on Vo pin from the pot? Maybe the problem is not the LCD connections, but AVR? Show the schematics.